# Using document.write() function to print while in a loop | RE: Browser Updates

Tags: javascript, loops

It appears that browser behavior has changed since I last attempted to print output to the user while iterating within a loop.  I am attempting to validate user input as it relates to conditions within my search array for a simple inventory list, and have it print out on the document while still iterating through the loop.  Now it seems the output only gets displayed once you quit the loop.

```
while (true) {
search = prompt("Search for a product in our store.  Type 'list' to show all of the produce and 'quit' to exit");

search = search.toLowerCase();
if (search === 'quit') {
    break;
} else if (search === 'list') {
    print(inStock.join(", "));
    continue;
} else {
    if (inStock.indexOf(search) > -1 ) {
        print("Yes, we have " + search + " in the store.");
    } else {
        print(search + "is not in stock.");
    }
  }
}
```

Parameters:

- type 'list' to view list
- type 'quit' to exit loop and view results (never used to function
  like this) type the name of the product you're searching for
- and then 'quit' to see the result.  (trying to bypass this oddity..)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9nfd62q7/

Comment: In firefox, it appears to be working exactly as you wanted using your jsfiddle.

Comment: In a general sense browsers don't repaint the screen while JS is still running. *Some* browsers, *may* do a repaint while a prompt or alert window is open, but when I tried your fiddle in Chrome I got the behaviour you described where it didn't paint until the end. You could use a `setTimeout()`-based pseudo loop instead of a `while` and the browser would repaint between iterations/timeouts. But...don't use `document.write` after the page has loaded (or at all, if you can help it, which in this case you can).

Comment: you would be better off appending a dom object then using your doc.write. The first time you use it, everything in your page is going to get stomped on.